How to resolve job skipping due to if condition with workflow_call input?
dependency-build.yaml:
name: Dependency-Build1

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      called_via_workflow_call:
        type: boolean
        default: false  # Default value if not triggered by workflow_call
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  check-changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      dependency_changed: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.dependency }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Filter changes
        id: changes
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
        with:
          filters: |
            dependency:
              - 'dependency-project01/**'

      # Debugging the output of the change detection
      - name: Debug Changes Output
        run: |
          echo "Changes Output: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.dependency }}"

  dependency-build:
    needs: check-changes
    if: needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == true && ${{ inputs.called_via_workflow_call == false }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Debug Job Start
        run: |
          echo "Dependency-build job started"

      # Debugging the values of outputs and inputs
      - name: Output Dependency Changed
        run: |
          echo "Dependency Changed: ${{ needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed }}"

      - name: Debug Workflow Call Input
        run: |
          echo "Called via Workflow: ${{ inputs.called_via_workflow_call }}"

      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Build Dependency Project
        run: |
          echo "Building Dependency Project..."


shared-build.yaml:
name: Shared-Build01

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'shared-project01/**'
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  complete-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Say Hello
        run: echo "The Shared-Build01 job has been completed successfully!"
      - name: Sleep for 30 seconds
        run: sleep 30s
        shell: bash

  call_dependency_build1:
    needs: complete-job
    uses: ./.github/workflows/dependency-build1.yml
    with:
      called_via_workflow_call: truename: Shared-Build01

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'shared-project01/**'
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  complete-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Say Hello
        run: echo "The Shared-Build01 job has been completed successfully!"
      - name: Sleep for 30 seconds
        run: sleep 30s
        shell: bash

  call_dependency_build1:
    needs: complete-job
    uses: ./.github/workflows/dependency-build1.yml
    with:
      called_via_workflow_call: true

I have a GitHub Actions workflow where I pass an input that defaults to false and set it to true when the workflow is called via workflow_call. I am using the following if condition for the dependency-build job:
if: needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == true && inputs.called_via_workflow_call == 'false'


When I test with just if: needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == true, the dependency-build job runs correctly when there are changes in dependency-project01.
However, when I use the full condition that includes inputs.called_via_workflow_call, the dependency-build job gets skipped, even when there are changes in dependency-project01, and the input defaults to false.

Why does this happen, and how can I resolve the issue to ensure the job runs as expected with the full condition?

Remove quotes around false i.e. inputs.called_via_workflow_call == false. See the inputs context. It's similar to this thread.

That was one of the issue. The current condition is partially working; it's triggering the independent dependency build when there is a change in dependency-project01. However, the condition isn't behaving as expected because my goal is to skip the dependency workflow when both shared-project01 and dependency-project01 have changes. This would prevent two pushes for the same dependency workflow. I want to ensure that the individual dependency build is skipped if both projects have changes at the same time. Could you help adjust the condition to achieve this? I edited files

According to your last revision, you're using if: needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == true && ${{ inputs.called_via_workflow_call == false }}. It should be if: ${{ needs.check-changes.outputs.dependency_changed == 'true' && inputs.called_via_workflow_call == false }}.

According to Passing information between jobs, "Outputs are Unicode strings". Also, check this example.
